# Нужно найти все значения с числом 1 и вывести полные пути до них

Tags: javascript

```
 var object = {
  list228: 1,
  otherList: {
    otherOtherList: {
        otherOtherListItem1: 1,
        otherOtherListItem2: 'blue'
      },
     otherOtherListItem1: 'red'
   }
};
```

в результате должно получиться

```
      "listItem1" 
    "subList > subSubList > subSubListItem1"
```

Comment: console.log(object) перед условием что показывает?

Comment: тоже самое, что и в условии)
но как оттуда путь вытащить ?

Comment: что вы конкретно пытались сделать (где код программы) ?

Comment: вывести все элементы с единицей

Comment: вам нужно перебрать все свойства объекта for(prop in object). Причем каждое свойство также может быть объектом, т.е.. функция будет рекурсивной. Вам нужно будет хранить "текущий путь" При переборе когда вы будете "заходить" в подобъект необходимо будет добавить "подобъект" к текущему пути. Этот путь нужно будет использовать для вашего результата